# I used this python script to make a snowflake but it doesn't make a snowflake

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, turtle-graphics

This is my script:

```
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()
poe = turtle.Turtle()
wn.bgcolor("grey")

colors = ["cyan", "purple", "white", "blue"]

poe.penup()
poe.forward(90)
poe.left(45)
poe.pendown()

def branch():
    for i in range(3):
        for i in range(3):
            poe.forward(30)
            poe.backward(30)
            poe.right(45)
        poe.left(90)
        poe.backward(30)
    poe.right(90)
    poe.forward(90)

for i in range(8):
    branch()
    poe.left(45)

wn.exitonclick()
```

I just draws a weird squareflake. I got this code from https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/turtle-snowflakes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the project again and compare with your code.  You're missing a line in your code:

```
def branch():
    for i in range(3):
        for i in range(3):
            poe.forward(30)
            poe.backward(30)
            poe.right(45)
        poe.left(90)
        poe.backward(30)
        poe.left(45) # <---- This line
    poe.right(90)
    poe.forward(90)
```

You also had a typo in the project link shared.  I would advise you to be more careful and double check your work.  A missing line, or character, or even a missed indentation can be catastrophic to your program.

Comment: here is the real link:  https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/turtle-snowflakes